# How to activate the aggregate option in Google Sheets API

Tags: python, google-api, python-requests, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to create a line chart in Google Sheets from python by the Google Sheets API. But I am not able to activate the Aggregate option.

```
                {
                    "addChart": {
                        "chart": {
                            "spec": {
                                "title": type,
                                "basicChart": {
                                    "chartType": "LINE",
                                    "legendPosition": "TOP_LEGEND",
                                    "axis": [
                                        # X-AXIS
                                        {
                                            "position": "BOTTOM_AXIS",
                                            "title": "Date"
                                        },
                                        # Y-AXIS
                                        {
                                            "position": "LEFT_AXIS",
                                            "title": "Number of "+type
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "domains": [
                                        {
                                            "domain": {
                                                "sourceRange": {
                                                    "sources": [
                                                        {
                                                            "sheetId": gid,
                                                            "startRowIndex": 0,
                                                            "endRowIndex": 1000000,
                                                            "startColumnIndex": 1,
                                                            "endColumnIndex": 2
                                                        }
                                                    ]
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "series": [
                                        {
                                            "series": {
                                                "sourceRange": {
                                                    "sources": [
                                                        {
                                                            "sheetId": gid,
                                                            "startRowIndex": 0,
                                                            "endRowIndex": 1000000,
                                                            "startColumnIndex": 9,
                                                            "endColumnIndex": 10
                                                        }
                                                    ]
                                                },
                                                "aggregateType": "SUM"
                                            },
                                            "targetAxis": "LEFT_AXIS"
                                        }...
```

As you can see above, I'm creating a linechart with adimpression data from another sheet. Everything works nice except the aggregation. I've added the 'aggregateType' = 'SUM' but it still don't work.
Do you guys have a solution for this issue?

I've looked for the solution but I couldn't find anything usefull. Someone talked about a .setOption('applyAggregateData', 0) but that solution doesn't works for me, I think I need some extra info in the request body.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Sheets API documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/charts#chartdata), the `aggregateType` field is only supported for Data Source charts, which are generated by BigQuery requests.

For aggregation to work you need to define your data source using the `dataSourceChartProperties` field in [ChartSpec](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/charts#chartspec).

```
"dataSourceChartProperties": {
  object (DataSourceChartProperties)
},
```

Additional information about Data Source objects can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/connected-sheets#working_with_datasource_objects).